# Default language problem on multilingual website

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a problem with default language. I have 2 languages (English and German), and the l18n module installed. The default language is English. I have added a content in English, and I translated it with Translate option. The path for the English content is en/content/article, and the path for German content is de/content/article.

After changing term translations, the language content is changed to German, while the default language for the site is still English. When I want to edit or add new content, that is in German (de/content/article), even if I set English.

I have German as default language in the content list; previously, it was English.

Can anyone help?

Comment: So you changed default languages after you already created some content?

Comment: No, I've never changed the default language. It's still english, but I've changed terms translation for one of vocabularies and i've changed translation mode for this vocabulary. And then I noted that in content list the default language is german and the original language for each article is german altough it was created in english :/

Comment: Now, evertime i want to create an article it is created with path de/content/article instead of en/content/article

Comment: Anyone have some idea, where should i search the problem?

Comment: I'm wondering if drupal core reinstallation could help to restore language settings. What do you thing?